# Don't complain about unmatching parenthesis and brackets in latex math mode

Tags: latex

In mathematical notation, parenthesis and brackets have overloaded meaning, and when it comes to represent intervals, the parenthesis/brackets don't have to match. For example,

```
(1, 2]
```

means an interval with left open and right closed. But unfortunately, in math mode in latex mode, this becomes fairly annoying that whenever notation likes this is used, emacs highlights it as error.

For example,

[image]

But outside of math mode, it's really not normal if any mismatches happen. I am wondering if you guys got a way to fix it?

---

enabled minor modes:

```
Enabled minor modes: Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Auto-Fill Auto-Revert Company Diff-Auto-Refine Electric-Indent
File-Name-Shadow Flyspell Font-Lock Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit
Global-Hi-Lock Global-Undo-Tree Hi-Lock Latex-Preview-Pane Line-Number Linum
Magit-Auto-Revert Magit-File Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Origami Override-Global Projectile
Pyvenv Rainbow-Delimiters Save-Place Shell-Dirtrack Show-Smartparens
Show-Smartparens-Global Tex-Pdf Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Yas
```

Comment: When starting from fundamental-mode, activating math-mode, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler are you saying it shouldn't complain? but it does here.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler i updated with my minor modes. i did try to play with smartparen but it does not seem related.

Comment: Sorry, my comment missed the point and it was to late for a delete. Probably worth a bug report.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler i am not even sure which party should fix this. should it be the latex mode or emacs?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? @HuStmpHrrr I have the same problem here.

Comment: @X.Arthur no I lived with it. Not even sure who to blame.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The issue is once there is one unbalanced, all the paren afterwards in the same .tex file will complain... Then I'd rather turn off the mode...

Comment: @X.Arthur yeah. But I don't really have the occasion to write unbalanced interval for now so it doesn't bother me anymore

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU the error message is sent by `blink-matching-open`. Calls a var holding `blink-matching-check-function`, which points to `blink-matching-check-mismatch`. Finally appears function `syntax-after` and the `char-table`.

Please consider reporting it at bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.

For the moment customizing var `blink-matching-paren` to nil avoids the error message - at some cost.

As for the face: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `show-paren-mismatch` <kbd>RET</kbd> might mitigate the distraction.

Finally <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `show-paren-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> to `off` avoids the highlighting.

Comment: hmm... it seems caused by something else. I set that variable to `nil`, then reopen the file again. but i can still see those highlights.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Customizing should affect error message - edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and found the culprit to be rainbow-delimeters, which is listed in the OP's list of minor modes.

A workaround is to disable rainbow-delimeters in LaTeX mode. In Doom Emacs, this can be accomplished by adding the following to your `config.el`:

```
(after! tex
  (remove-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook #'rainbow-delimiters-mode))
```

Comment: I am using Doom Emacs and this worked for me. Thanks!